# SQL Always encrypted - Key Vault powershell Interactive logon issues

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

Today after many months (and possibly for the first time on my new PC) have gone to update my powershell encrypt/decrypt scrips. During testing though, I can't get interactive authentication working (Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -Interactive).

When I follow the process and logon with my account, it's now giving me an error AADSTS500200 that I can't use a personal account unless explicitly invited to an organization. Given I've only EVER used that one account with the Key Vault, and it's the owner of the Azure account, I'm super confused.

I can't find anything, have managed to revert to using the client secret thankfully, although I'd prefer to keep using interactive.

What am I missing!?

Comment: A lot of Azure logon issues are due to it automatically using the _wrong_ account. It uses some other cached account, and there is seemingly no way to make it use the right account. So first piece of investigation is: is it using the account you think it is?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to check. It definitely triggers the authenticator app for 2FA during the auth flow, but i have 2 accounts hooked up to that. It does look to be using the right account as best as I can tell though.

Answer (score -1):

[Temp Auth Changes warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9f1h.png)

Well I found the reason, temporary changes to the authentication allowed in the AD App Registration. Hopefully changed soon.